# SQLite pode ser considerado um banco de dados relacional?

Tags: banco-de-dados, sqlite

Segundo [Wikipédia](http://www.devmedia.com.br/bancos-de-dados-relacionais-artigo-revista-sql-magazine-86/20401),
Um banco de dados relacional é um banco de dados que modela os dados de uma forma que eles sejam percebidos pelo usuário como tabelas, ou mais formalmente relações.

No meu entendimento `SQLite` se encaixa nesta definição (e outras que pesquisei)

Porém, na documentação desta implementação fiquei intrigado com os métodos separando o `SQLite`dos `Banco de dados relacionais`:

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Afinal, o `SQLite` pode ser considerado um banco de dados relacional?

Comment: Não é nem questão de considerar, ele é mesmo. A diferença na descrição é só especialização da biblioteca usada. No primeiro caso, "um relacional em geral", no segundo, o SQLite.em específico (não teria muito sentido nem necessidade de escrever "when targeting the relational database SQLite")

Comment: @Bacco essa é a resposta mesmo, talvez um pouco mais elaborada :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com certeza.
Como qualquer outro esquema relacional, o SQLite oferece processos de

- validação, verificação e garantias de **integridade dos dados**,
- Suporte a chaves estrangeiras, trigger e autoincremento
- controle de concorrência, recuperação de falhas, segurança,
- controle de **transações**, otimização de consultas

As limitações do SQLite estão mais relacionados a performance, isto é, não é recomendado em um ambiente servidor que será muito requisitado. Como é um sistema embarcado, é muito usado em aplicações distribuídas, sem a necessidade de instalar nenhum SGDB, uma  vez que os drivers vão junto com a aplicação.

o conceito de banco de dados não relacional (noSQL) se refere a modelos que não permitem SQL, em situações onde os dados não são modelados na forma de tabelas. Razões:

- dificuldade em se conciliar tal modelo com a demanda por escalabilidadecada vez mais frequente.
- dificuldade em se organizar os dados em um sistema distribuído trabalhando com particionamento de dados

> Citação https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL
>   Citação http://pt.slideshare.net/alexculpado/jose-alexandrerdbm-sxnosql

Comment: O SQLLite só não é recomendado onde tem muita escrita concorrente. è comum em muitas situações típicas, se a pessoa que está usado souber o que está fazendo, ele ter mais performance que outros bancos, afinal muitas escritas concorrentes não é típico.

Answer (score 1):

Eu só queria contribuir com meus dois centavos.

**Sim**. SQLite é um sistema gerenciador de banco de dados relacional pelo simples fato de usar a linguagem SQL, como o nome supõe. Em contraste, existem os bancos de dados NoSQL (MongoDB, Cassandra e Redris, e.g.).

Veja, um exemplo de inserção de dados no [**MongoDB**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/introduction/):

```
db.users.insertMany(
  [
     {
       _id: 5,
       name: "xyz",
       age: 23,
       type: 2,
       status: "D",
       favorites: { artist: "Noguchi", food: "nougat" },
       finished: [ 14, 6 ],
       badges: [ "orange" ],
       points: [
          { points: 71, bonus: 20 }
       ]
     },
     {
       _id: 6,
       name: "abc",
       age: 43,
       type: 1,
       status: "A",
       favorites: { food: "pizza", artist: "Picasso" },
       finished: [ 18, 12 ],
       badges: [ "black", "blue" ],
       points: [
          { points: 78, bonus: 8 },
          { points: 57, bonus: 7 }
       ]
     }
  ]
)
```

SQL é uma linguagem estruturada para gerir dados de sistemas de dados relacionais (que seguem o modelo relacional proposto por Codd), principalmente, sistemas gerenciadores de banco de dados, como Oracle Database 12c, MS SQL Server, MySQL, SQLite, etc.

Exemplo (com sintaxe pouco comum) com SQL:

```
-- MS SQL Server Query: A tabela do exemplo tem 5 campos, sendo um deles auto incrementável (chave-primária (IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY)
INSERT INTO minha_tabela
VALUES(
    'Valor 1' -- [N]VARCHAR
    ,1 -- TINYINT
    ,'2017-01-12 02:59:12' --DATETIME
    ,(SELECT TOP(1) nome FROM MEU_BD.DBO.tabela_usuarios) -- [N]VARCHAR
);
```